# Zoom-SDK Duplicate class com.google.android.exoplayer

Tags: android-studio, duplicates, build.gradle, exoplayer, zoom-sdk

i'm using lastest version of zoom-sdk, and i'm getting the following error:

```
Duplicate class com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.spherical.package-info found in modules exoplayer-core-2.16.1-runtime (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.16.1) and library-core-release-runtime (library-core-release.aar)
Duplicate class com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.spherical.TouchTracker$Listener found in modules exoplayer-core-2.16.1-runtime (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.16.1) and library-core-release-runtime (library-core-release.aar)
Duplicate class com.google.android.exoplayer2.video.spherical.TouchTracker found in modules exoplayer-core-2.16.1-runtime (com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.16.1) and library-core-release-runtime (library-core-release.aar)
......
```

And

```
implementation("com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-datasource:2.17.0") { exclude group: "com.google.android.exoplayer", module: "exoplayer-common" }
implementation("com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-decoder:2.17.0") { exclude group: "com.google.android.exoplayer", module: "exoplayer-common" }
```

in my build.gradle(:app) for video player, when i remove implementations app works fine with zoom-sdk but video player no longer work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your project uses two versions of exoplayer, "2.17.0" and "2.16.1".
Replace your implementation of Exoplayer with this:

```
implementation("com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core") {
    version {
        strictly("2.17.1")
    }
}

implementation("com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui") {
    version {
        strictly("2.17.1")
    }
}
```

This will force your project to use one version of Exoplayer as "2.17.1"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).